# Setting ViewModel Property from Method in Another Project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Beginner here - I'm struggling to wrap my head around accessing viewmodel properties. In my particular case, I have a solution containing two different projects. One contains the UI components, the other the majority of the "work."

My viewmodel in my UI project contains the following property:

```
   private int _createfileprogress { get; set; }

   public int CreateFileProgress
    {
        get { return _createfileprogress ; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _createfileprogress )
                return;

            _createfileprogress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CreateFileProgress");
        }
    }
```

The purpose of this int property is to fill in the progress of a progress bar. I'd like to reference it in my other project, where a long-running method is executed as such:

```
    public void LongRunningMethod()
    {
        CreateFileProgress= 0;

        // Do some calculations

        CreateFileProgress= 10

        // More calculations and external calls

        CreateFileProgress= 20

        // etc.
    }
```

But I can't find the right way to connect these two. I'm sure doing this wrong - would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156390/display-progress-during-matrix-loop/46158169#46158169 check this answer out, I made a progressbar window that supports binding

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand your question.
Your ViewModels and the View are in the same Project und you want to monitor the progress from the Model which is in an another Project?

i think you are searching for Events / Observer Pattern

In MVVM the Model didn't care about the ViewModel and the View.
The Prober Way in MVVM is that the model raise Events which the Viewmodel can subscribe.

General Event Example in .Net

You can create an EventArgs Class like

```
    public class ProgressEventArgs :EventArgs
    {
        public int CurrentProgress { get; }

        public ProgressEventArgs(int progress)
        {
            CurrentProgress = progress;
        }
    }
```

and create the Event in your Model (LongRunningMethod) Class

```
    public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
    protected void OnProgressChanged(int progress)
    {
        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, new ProgressEventArgs(progress));
    }
```

So your Method can raise Events

```
    public void LongRunningMethod()
    {
        OnProgressChanged(0);

        // Do some calculations

        OnProgressChanged(10);

    // More calculations and external calls

        OnProgressChanged(20);

    // etc.
    }
```

which the ViewModel subscribe

```
    public class ProgressViewModel
    {
        public ProgressViewModel()
        {
            var model = new Model();
            model.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) => {
                //invoke ui thread
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                  new Action(() => 
                   {
                     CreateFileProgress = e.CurrentProgress; 
                   }));

            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would I create the EventArgs class in the model or the viewmodel?

Comment: i would it create in the model

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what might best help you would be to set the DataContext of your UI element (either the Window, the Page, or the ProgressBar itself) to your ViewModel, which will allow your UI to be bound to ViewModel properties. Since your ViewModel seems to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, your OnPropertyChanged() method should automatically keep the UI up-to-date when you use DataBinding.

**You'll first want to make a reference to your class library project that contains the "work".** This will allow your "UI project" to access the resources (namely, the ViewModel) from the "work project". Do this by right-clicking *References* under your "UI Project" in the Solution Explorer, choose *Add Reference...*, find the *Projects* tab on the left side, then check the box for your "work project". Apply it and your "UI project" can now access your "work project".

Once that is done, you can use either of the following methods to produce the result I believe you're looking for:

#### Set the Window's DataContext to your ViewModel

*(Best for when many elements within your Window will use resources from your ViewModel)*

```
<Window
    //Some attributes
    //Some more attributes
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyWorkProject.ViewModels;assembly=MyWorkProject">        
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding CreateFileProgress}/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### OR

#### Set only the ProgressBar's DataContext using a StaticResources

*(Best if you don't need the entire Window's DataContext to be the ViewModel)*

```
<Window
    //Some attributes
    //Some more attributes
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyWorkProject.ViewModels;assembly=MyWorkProject">        
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}, Path=CreateFileProgress}/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```